# Using "and" with names that have "and" in them

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis

> I taught him Microprocessor and Interfacing and Professional Ethics.

Here *Microprocessor and Interfacing* is the first subject, and *Professional Ethics* is the second.  The same professor taught me these two subjects.

What is the proper way to write this sentence?

Comment: Try using the ampersand for a closer connect. Use a comma for disambiguation. *Microprocessor & Interfacing, and Professional Ethics.* This is not necessarily "the proper" way to write, but it works.

Comment: @Kris That sounds better.  I will use that untill I find a better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He was my student in Microprocessor and Interfacing, and Professional Ethics.

(When speaking, you would use a pause to separate the two class names. The comma serves the same purpose. Personally, I would also say "and in" rather than "and" in this case, for the same reason... but that's officially optional.)

Comment: You don't need the second "in." This is a perfect example of an Oxford comma (albeit with only two entries in the list).

Comment: You don't _need_ the second "in", agreed. However, I would use it for clarity.

Comment: @DrRandy The Oxford comma has its uses, as in this case.

Comment: I'm a fan of the Oxford, Kris :)